# Update XML with C# running from command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, jenkins, cmd

Working with: visual studio and C#
I have function to update XML file, while running from the VS it's works and the XML is updated.
While running this function out from the VS for example command line or Jenkins the XML file doesn't update.
My code:

```
string XMLPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())));
public void UpdateXML(string tag, string value)
{
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string XMLFile = "";
try{
    XMLFile = XMLPath + "\\Test.xml";
    doc.Load(XMLFile);        
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(tag);
    node.InnerText = value;
    doc.Save(XMLFile);
    }
catch (Exception e){}
}

public void Set_ConfigurationXML()
{
UpdateXML("Platform", "web");
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you running it. Can you provide the main function?

Comment: there is a catch block what is the exception e you are getting?

Comment: Running it from command line, it is runs but just doesn't update the XML. There is no exception all goes as expected.

Comment: Issue resolved, it was a path error.